# R/ggplot2: figure legend for size has weird blobs covering sample data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, legend

Surprised not to be able to find this here, I'm guessing this is a common problem.

I'm drawing boxplots in ggplot, plus plotting the data points themselves with geom_point() or geom_jitter().  When I set a size aesthetic for the points, the legend is obscured by dark blobs over the example data points.

```
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(
a = factor(c( rep('a',5), rep('b',5), rep('c',5) )), b = rnorm(15),
c = rnorm(15)
)
ggplot( aes( x = a, y = b, size = c), data = d ) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
     geom_jitter(width = 0.3)
```

[image: blobby size legends]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those blobs are coming from the size aesthetic getting applied to geom_boxplot(), leading to legend weirdness.  The solution is to apply size aesthetics only to geom_point/jitter().

```
ggplot( aes( x = a, y = b), data = d ) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_jitter( aes( size=c ), width = 0.3)
```

[image: fixed legend]